# Oracle nvl not able to handle empty string even after using is not null

Tags: sql, oracle, null

I am trying to return empty or dummy string if select query returns `null`.I tried using dummy value in `NVL(colum,'dummy')`, but I am still getting `no data found` error.
Below is what I tried:

**1.**

```
  SELECT de.destination INTO l_sub_ent

  FROM dest de

  where de.destination='somevalue' AND de.destination IS NOT NULL;
```

**2.**

```
  SELECT COALSECE(de.destination, 'dummy') INTO l_sub_ent

  FROM dest de

  where de.destination ='some value';
```

**3.**

```
  SELECT NVL(de.desc_en, 'dummy') INTO l_sub_ent

  FROM dest de

  where de.destination ='some value';
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is not that your `de.destination` is `NULL`. There are no records for the condition `de.destination='somevalue'`. Handle it something like this.

```
SELECT Count(1)
INTO   v_count
FROM   dest de
WHERE  de.destination='somevalue';

IF v_count > 0 THEN
  SELECT NVL(de.destination,'dummy')
  INTO   l_sub_ent
  FROM   dest de
  WHERE  de.destination='somevalue';
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve using below :

```
SELECT NVL(MIN(val), 'dummy') INTO l_sub_ent

  FROM dest de

  where de.destination ='some value';
```